# "racoon" brand mouse: back/forward buttons not working

Tags: mouse

The mouse brand "racoon" doesn't recognize the back/forward buttons.

I checked my device id and checked that the driver should be ok in the kernel here:

- https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:1ea7-0064

How do I install the driver with support for the back/forward buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I checked and it was imwheel who interfere with the ability to use back/forward buttons.

So instead of executing imwheel normally, I use:
imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"

With this config, the buttons back/forward works